# Storing values of @PathVariable in @RequestBody object, a good practice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, spring-restcontroller

I'm writing a POST api in my `@RestController`.

Following rest best practice,the url is

```
/v1/myapi/bank/{bank_id}/branch/{branch_id}
```

The API also takes other parameters as input in the form of `@RequestBody BankDetails`.

```
class BankDetails {
    String address;
    String zip;
    // Constructor, getters & setters
}
```

For some reason I want to put this request into a queue (*AWS SQS in this case*), i.e. `BankDetails` object with associated `bank_id` & `branch_id`.

For storing it as one object, I've modified the `BankDetails` class to include `bank_id` & `branch_id`.

Like:

```
class BankDetails {
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    String bankId;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    String branchId;

    String address;
    String zip;
    // Contructor, getters & setters
}
```

I've also modified `@PostMapping` method in `@RestController` to feed the data.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/myapi/bank/{bank_id}/branch/{branch_id}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> createBankBranch(
    @PathVariable(name = "bank_id") String bankId,
    @PathVariable(name = "branch_id") String branchId,
    @RequestBody BankDetails bankDetails) {

        // Added these 2 lines.
        bankDetails.setBankId(bankId);
        bankDetails.setbrnachId(branchId);
}
```

Is this a good practice to first get parameters in path & feed the same in **RequestBody** object?

P.S. I cannot use `/v1/myapi/bank/{bank_id}`, because that's a separate API.

Answer (score 1):

Simply `POST /myapi/bank` and all the details as DTO and dont worry about anything.

I dont think you have followed "best practices" as AFAIK this path you have provided would be used to eg modify branch with given id in context of given bank_id, not the bank itself

For example, having `PUT /bank/bankId/vault/cash` could eg modify overall amount of cash in given bank (stupid, but i think its fine as showcase), not the bank itself, but this is what you try to do.